# SQL: Agrupar por Max() pero sin que se repita un registro? en una tabla de valores repetidos?

Tags: sql, delphi

Estoy guardando un log de otra tabla en esta tabla.
De esta tabla: `Select * from continent_log.DB`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces quiero saber el resumen de la fecha de entrada de los regsitros, para eso se utiliza el `idGhost` máximo correspondiente a ese `idContinent`

siguiendo con el problema, quiero sacar una agrupación de los distintos `idContinent` con sus repectivos `idGhost` máximos, `name`, `inputDate`, `inputTime`

e.g. para el idContinent 7 debería tener el idGhost 8
e.g. para el idContinent 8 debería tener el idGhost 8

Hasta aquí la pregunta.

---

Otra cosa la sintaxis de la subconsulta no me reconoce el gestor bbdd: 
`select col from (select... )`

Gracias de ante mano.

La tabla `Continent.db` es esta, por si acaso: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy utilizando en Borland Database Engine (SQL explorer 4.0) que viene junto con el C++ Builder 6

Comment: Left join trae todos los de la izquierda, sin importar si hay valores a la derecha. Con inner join solucionas eso. Pero mas alla de eso, si queres traer datos de la tabla continente y queres que la respuesta te ayude con eso, necesitamos verla y saber que campos necesitas. Si no, tu respuesta es un select con un group by simple

Comment: Igual en esta pregutna hay que aclarar dos cosas. Que motor de base de datos usas. y delphi aca no tiene nada que ver.

Comment: Si perdona, he subido al final esas dos cosas ya las he puesto. Pero volviendo a lo de la consulta, ya intenté lo del inner join. tampoco funcionó.

Comment: y la tabla continentid la usas para algo? porque por lo que veo, todo esta en la tabla de logs

Comment: si la tabla `continent.db` es el origen y la tabla de log pues es como su nombre indica para guardar los cambios de esos registros. Es correcto la tabla de log tiene lo que la otra pero tiene más que eso.

Comment: BDE tiene ya muchos años de haber sido declarado _obsoleto_ en Delphi, es recomendable migrar a otras capas de conexión, pues no tiene soporte y eventualmente va a dejar de funcionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes hacerlo con una única consulta (una única `SELECT` quiero decir), puesto que tal y como has dicho hay valores repetidos que afectan a los datos que quieres extraer.

La sintaxis concreta puede variar segun el motor de Bases de Datos que estés utilizando, pero esta por ejemplo funciona con SQL Server.

```
Select * from contionent_log A
INNER JOIN 
   (select Max(id) id2, IdContinent IdContinent2, Max(idGhost) idGhost2 
    from contionent_log=
    group by IdContinent) B
ON A.id=B.id2
```

En la `SELECT` interior obtienes realmente los registros que necesitas y la exterior (con la INNER JOIN) la utilizamos para obtener el resto de campos de la tabla.

Es posile que haya otras opciones, como utilizar un `SELECT..IN`, pero esta me ha parecido sencilla y fácil de entender. Creo además que es más  óptima que otras posibles soluciones.

Comment: Esta es la respuesta que soluciona mi pregunta. Al no poder utilizar una subconsulta lo comprobé metiéndolo en una nueva tabla y he comprobado que funciona. Intentaré leer un poco más la documentación de mi gestor bbdd, para hayar una alternativa a la subconsulta. Muchas gracias @German